# How to find the world coordinates of the SkinnedMeshRenderer's BoundingBox

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a script like this:

This is the code that moves the object near the origin by looking at the coordinates of the bounding box.

**MeshCheck.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    Mesh mesh;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject topGrp = GameObject.Find("GameObject");

        var MeshRenderer = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        var SkinnedMeshRenderer = GetComponent<SkinnedMeshRenderer>();
        if (MeshRenderer != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("this is MeshRenderer");
            Bounds bounds = MeshRenderer.bounds;
            float meshCenterX = bounds.center.x;
            float meshMinCenterY = bounds.center.y - bounds.extents.y;
            float meshScenterZ = bounds.center.z;
            topGrp.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-meshCenterX, -meshMinCenterY, -meshScenterZ);
        }
        else if(SkinnedMeshRenderer != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("this is SkinnedMeshRenderer");
            Bounds bounds = SkinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh.bounds;
            float meshCenterX = bounds.center.x;
            float meshMinCenterY = bounds.center.y - bounds.extents.y;
            float meshScenterZ = bounds.center.z;
            topGrp.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(-meshCenterX, -meshMinCenterY, -meshScenterZ);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("this is not mesh");
        }
    }
}
```

To test the above code, create an Empty GameObject named "GameObject" and place a Cube etc. in it. Then, after moving the Cube, press the Start button and confirm that the Cube moves to the origin.Then attach MeshCheck.cs to the Cube.

[image]

In the above code, it worked fine if the object had a MeshRenderer.

But when the object had a SkinnedMeshRenderer, it didn't work as expected.

The bounding box value of SkinnedMeshRenderer is relative coordinates, while the bounding box value of MeshRenderer is world coordinates, so I think this behavior may occur.

Is there a way to get the world coordinates of the bounding box in SkinnedMeshRenderer as well as in MeshRenderer?

The SkinnedMeshRenderer may be scaled under the influence of bones. I want it to work properly even in such cases.

Comment: Afaik `.bounds` should still be global .. do you mean the `.localBounds`?

Comment: No, I'm talking about `.bounds`, not `.localBounds`. I used `SkinnedMeshRenderer.sharedMesh.bounds` to check the values of `meshCenterX, Y, Z` after moving the bones skinning the mesh. However, those values do not seem to change. This means that the values we can get with `.bounds` are not world coordinates.At least in SkinnedMeshRenderer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you revealed that actually you are using

```
SkinneMeshRenderer.sharedMesh.bounds
```

but note that this way you are getting the [`Mesh.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh-bounds.html) which indeed are local to the mesh coordinate space.

> This is the axis-aligned bounding box of the mesh in its local space (that is, not affected by the transform). Note that the `Renderer.bounds` property is similar but returns the bounds in world space.

Also the `sharedMesh` is the original one shared between all instances and not affected by the skinning yet ;)

---

What you want instead would be

```
SkinnedMeshRenderer.bounds
```

in order to get the world space bounds of this renderer instance. See [`Renderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html)

> The bounding volume of the renderer (Read Only).
>
> This is the axis-aligned bounding box fully enclosing the object in
> world space.
>
> Note that the Mesh.bounds property is similar but returns the bounds
> of the mesh in local space.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer solved my problem.